# What's the best way to store REST API responses in Cucumber

Tags: java, spring, rest, cucumber, e2e-testing

I'm going to build e2e tests for my RESTful API and use `Cucumber` for this.
I'm also going to use `cucumber-spring` to share the state between StepDefs.

Let's assume that the RESTful API is about zoo. Here're some scenarios below.

- customer registers at the zoo site with login/password. I need to store customer ID in the state. Also I need to store full http response for registration as I want to be able to check that if customer provides too weak password, the http response contains correct http status code.
- customer buys a ticker to the zoo. I need to store the ticket ID and the response as well, for the same reasons.

OK, it's easy so far. But what if:

- customer buys another ticket. If I use the same definition as for the first ticket, it will reuse the same state variable, and the first one won't be available any more. If I create another definition, I will have duplicated code that will make mess.
- another customer registers and buys a ticket, so I want to ensure that zoo is not overcrowded. The same question here as above - what definition should I use and what state variable?

Answer (score 1):

The [NoraUi](https://noraui.github.io) framework makes this a singleton class life (https://github.com/NoraUi/NoraUi/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/noraui/utils/Context.java).

You can use this mechanism to store variables in a context. It is then possible to reset the context with each scenario (or each `example` in case of `Scenario Outline`).

```
public static void saveValue(String key, String value) {
    getInstance().scenarioRegistry.put(key, value);
}

public static String getValue(String key) {
    return getInstance().scenarioRegistry.get(key);
}
```

In your cucumber code, you can use for write:

```
Context.saveValue(targetKey, targetStringValue);
```

In your cucumber code, you can use for read:

```
String value = Context.getValue(textOrKey) != null ? Context.getValue(textOrKey) : textOrKey;
```

Comment: Thanks, but cucumber-spring makes the same actually. The question is about something different - how to write definitions and store responses in case when a request is called multiple times.

Comment: You can registre any list in context instand of string (in this sample)

Comment: I can put any class in context for sure, not only collections. Do you suggest to always write StepDefinitions storing values in collections? like `@When("I register") { customerRegistrationResponses.add(response);}` ? Does it look convenient to work with?

Comment: @MikhailKopylov, yes

Answer (score 1):

The simple solution is to not try and re-use your step definitions so much. One of the biggest mistakes people make with Cucumber is to try and get lots of reuse with step definitions. Its really not at all important how many step definitions you have so long as your step definitions share helper methods.

**following in ruby, but I'm sure you can translate**

```
When 'I buy a ticket' do 
  @ticket = buy_ticket
end

When 'I buy a second ticket' do
  @second_ticket = buy_ticket
end

When 'I buy a discounted ticket' do
  @discount_ticket = buy_ticket
end 

When 'I buy a family ticket' do
  @family_ticket = buy_ticket
end
```

Now the rest of your scenario can talk about the second_ticket or the family_ticket.

Note: there is no duplication here, all the steps are calling the same method to create the ticket (you can use parameters to deal with and additional complexity buy_ticket may need to support).

Comment: Thanks, looks you are experienced with Cucumber. So all scenarios may use second_ticket or family_ticket variables since they are in the scope. Doesn't this pollute the overall scope?

Comment: Cucumber has a concept of a World, which is to all intent a global scope. This is by design based on the idea that anything ambiguous in this global scope is ambiguous in your understanding of your business domain, and that the best solution to this is to remove the ambiguity with naming rather than allow the ambiguity by namespacing. You have to be very disciplined when using this technique - no 30 line scenarios with multiple variables. My rules are >7 lines stinks,  > 5lines smells, more than 3 variables stinks. With that discipline it works really well.

Comment: Note also that the helper methods are in the global scope (at least in ruby). So the real art is to use as few helper methods as possible whilst keeping them simple, and to be really precise and disciplined with naming

Comment: Thanks, I like this idea. You mentioned that it's the simple solution. Are there any other ones, may be not so elegant?

Comment: There are a tonne of ways to Cuke badly, I've probably done quite a few of them in my time, and still make mistakes now. But I'm not going to tell you about them for two reasons. 1) I don't have much recent experience of them so I'm not really qualified. 2) I don't want to recommend bad ways to do something.